# Is it possible to put the Uber organs into the shared stash?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I would like to know, if it is possible to collect the Uber organs (horn, eye and brain) with character-1 (Necro) in order to do Uber-Tristram with character-2 (Pala).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, anything that you can put in your personal stash can also be placed into the shared one.

Comment: I am not sure but I think this is wrong.